# TypeError: Wrong input type "String" for args

Tags: node.js, caching, redis

I'm trying to create a connection between nodejs and redisql i fall into problem when creating table something called `TypeError: Wrong input type "String" for args`
the stacktrace will be added at the end of post, i have added

```
const redisql = require('redisql');
const sqlClient = redisql.createClient();
sqlClient.create_table("employee", " id int , name TEXT , salary double ", redisql.print);
```

once i run the third command i get this stack trace

```
TypeError: Wrong input type "String" for args
    at RedisClient.send_command.RedisClient.sendCommand (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\node_modules\redis\lib\extendedApi.js:27:19)
    at rsql_send_command (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\node_modules\redisql\index.js:28:22)
    at RedisClient.proto.CREATE_TABLE (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\node_modules\redisql\index.js:47:5)
    at new Cache (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\app\index.js:11:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\app\index.js:45:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\index.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
TypeError: Wrong input type "String" for args
extendedApi.js:27
    at RedisClient.send_command.RedisClient.sendCommand (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\node_modules\redis\lib\extendedApi.js:27:19)
    at rsql_send_command (d:\BuildProjects\redisproject\node_modules\redisql\index.js:28:22)
    a
```

i followed this  project [link](https://github.com/mranney/node_Redisql/blob/master/examples/redisql_examples.js) in order to build mine

have no idea why, i read deeply the code and it seems it should be okay. could someone help me ?

Comment: Any clue to solve this?